# How does an MVC app know where to redirect the user when using the [Authorize] attribute?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

If you setup an MVC app with authentication and use the `[Authorize]` tag, it will automatically redirect unauthenticated users to the login view.

But how does it know that page *is* the login page? I've looked through a example app, but couldn't find anything obvious.

*edit*

I forgot to mention that I'm using MVC6.

Comment: Take a look in `App_Start` folder at the `Startup.Auth.cs` file, the login page is in there.

Comment: In MVC6, its the CookieAuthenticationMiddleware which does this.https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/715790c2134d5bd8904da65877c1fd4bce4b8035/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity/BuilderExtensions.cs#L20

Answer (score 1):

You might find it in your web.config, in

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <authentication mode="Forms">
            <forms loginUrl="~/Login" name=".ASPXFORMSAUTH" timeout="1440" />
        </authentication>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Further reading: [Jon Galloway: Looking at how the ASP.NET MVC Authorize interacts with ASP.NET Forms Authorization](http://weblogs.asp.net/jongalloway/looking-at-how-asp-net-mvc-authorize-interacts-with-asp-net-forms-authorization)

Comment: I forgot to mention I'm using MVC6. There are no web.configs.

Comment: Yeah, that does change things! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the template you used to create your app, if you look in the `App_Start` folder, there is a file called `Startup.Auth.cs`. The code in there sets up the authentication. This is the code from the default MVC template:

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
    AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
    LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
    Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
    {
        // Enables the application to validate the security stamp when the user logs in.
        // This is a security feature which is used when you change a password or add an 
        //external login to your account.  
        OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator
            .OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
                validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
                regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user
                    .GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
    }
});
```

Comment: I am actually playing around with the latest version of MVC, in VS 2015. All I see is a Startup.cs file.

Comment: MVC6 is very different from MVC5.